# When looping through the model, each attribute is showing up in views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I have a model `Article`, and in the controller i have

```
@articles = Article.all
```

In views I have:

```
<%=@articles.each do |article|%>
  <h1><%=article.title%></h1><br>
<%end%>
```

but in views, instead of just showing the article content, like it should, it is displaying each attribute of the object:

`[#<Article id: 11, title: "So this is my first post", content: "i am super exicited about this", created_at: "2016-01-08 19:50:10", updated_at: "2016-01-08 19:50:10">]`

Comment: <%-@articles.each do |article|%>   is what it should be.  The = in the ERB tag will show the entire article object.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<% @articles.each do |article|%>` instead of `<%= @articles.each do |article| %>`